# List of users in SimpleMembership is returning empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, simplemembership

EDIT - I got it working. I had orignally created a seperate context and viewmodel for my user classes. I moved everything into the same model/context/viewmodel as the rest of my entities and it works.

---

I'm new to simple membership and am trying to get a list of users from the aspnetusers table. The purpose being to manage those users - set roles, etc. My code runs, but the query returns empty, despite there being users in the db.

my context...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using userModel;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace tvc.DAL
{
    public class usersContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


d.creation_Date).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogin>().HasKey(e => e.UserId);
        }

        public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

my controller...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using tvc.DAL;
using userModel;

namespace tvc.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private usersContext db = new usersContext();
        // GET: User
        //[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<AspNetUser> u = db.AspNetUsers.ToList();
            return View(u);
        }
    }
}
```

u returns successfully, but is null. I can go to the database in ssms and query the user table successfully.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you verified that it is pointing to the right database?

Comment: `u` definitely should not be null.  It may be a list with 0 items in it.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes - not null - Count = 0

Comment: enki - there is no connection to any other database, and when I register a new user, the user is created in the database I'm targeting. I do still wonder if its somehow reading from the local default db though.